# Disable <iframe> onclick pause

Tags: html, youtube-api

I want to remove all controls from the user. I used: `controls=0` to hide the controls and `disablekb=1` to remove the keyboard shortcuts. The last left is the mouse click. I did some research, I didn't find the needed answer.

tl;dr How do I remove the mouse pause form an  such as this:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/EgBWDPXF2gU?autoplay=1&disablekb=1&controls=0&origin=http://example.com' ></iframe>
```

EDIT: There is a legal solution. It doesn't work on 100%, but it will be good enough for most cases. The solution is to simply add an event listener which is looking for the "video is paused event" When this event is triggered, simply start playing the current video. That will work flawlessly and unless the user clicks as fast as around 150-180 clicks per minute the difference for the millisecond when the video was paused before the function ran will be unnoticeable.

I will mark the only submitted answer as the solution simply because if anyone finds this he should, at first, know that any further modifications are illegal.

Comment: Did you try to place an element over iframe?

Comment: Hadn't occurred to me. I will give it a go. Though a hard place might be making the background of the 'upper' div transperant

Comment: Yep, I am thinking of a div that is invisible by default and when you need to disable the iframe and user interaction, make that div visible, with some alpha for example.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty decent shot to me. I am on it. If something nice comes up, I will update the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say but that is not a legal action. You could be banned for that from youtube. https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

Comment: Those terms are huge and quite hard to read! Could you kindly point specifically where it says this is ilegal?

Answer (score 9):

Try this trick for iframe or iframe wrapper:

```
#ytplayer {pointer-events: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="pointer-events: none">
  <iframe
    width="1730"
    height="683"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vSfAPWcrltQ"
    title="YouTube video player"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
    allowfullscreen
  ></iframe>
</div>
```

```
<div style="pointer-events: none">
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to disabled the click (if you really need to), put a div on your iframe with these CSS attributes:

```
position: absolute, 
height: 100%,
width: 100%
```