# Embedded YouTube video

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, embed

I want to embed a youtube video such that the user cannot do anything to change how the video is displayed.  I don't want them to be able to pause, fast forward, rewind, or watch the video again.  I am having troubles doing this.

I have gotten rid of the bar at the top and bottom and have tried to get rid of keyboard controls, but this has failed.  Here is a list of my current issues:

1. There is a YouTube video that appears when the mouse hovers over the video.  This takes you to the YouTube site.  I don't want this to be available.
2. Even though I did "disablekb=1", you can still use the keyboard to control the video.
3. You can pause the video by clicking on it.
4. At the very end after the video is over, there is a bar at the top wherein the user can click on a link to the video in YouTube.  I don't want this to be available.
5. Also at the very end after the video is over, you can click on a button to replay the video.

Here is my current code (using a YouTube video as a placeholder for the one that will actually be in there):

```
 <iframe width="640" height="360" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/RMINSD7MmT4?modestbranding=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;fs=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;disablekb=1&amp;rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I did find a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910931/disable-iframe-onclick-pause), but I am not sure how to implement this.  Plus, it only takes care of one of the problems.

If I can't do this what I want with YouTube, are there other sites that might work better?

Comment: I can only read that the video is copyrighted...

Comment: Chose a different one that should work now.

Comment: Try looking into their API. I think you can strip a lot away, if I remember correctly.

Comment: do you want the user to see the video ?

Comment: I definitely want the user to see the video, yes.  But I don't want them to be able to control the video at all or to be able to go to any links to the video at YouTube.com - just want them to stay at my page.

Comment: When I go to [the embedded youtube player demo page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo), and when I do the 'disablekb=1' option, I still am able to use my keyboard...I don't get it.